# how to check whether the table is empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

hie all,
i want to insert the data into the table only if the table is empty, so for that i need to check the condition to check whether data already exists in the table, if present then i want to empty the table before inserting the the fresh value.
i know how to insert and delete the data only prob is to check the condition. so please can any help me out in this.

***TO INSERT***

```
Dim comUserSelect As OleDbCommand

        myDateTime(i) = DateTime.Parse(arr_dateTime(i))
        '  Console.WriteLine(r("P1"))
        Dim strSELEsCTa As Integer = r("P1")
        If ins < 10 Then
            ins = ins + 1

            Dim strSELECTa As String = "insert into tblvalues (DataTime ,P1) values ('" & DateTime.Parse(arr_dateTime(i)) & "','" & strSELEsCTa & "')"

            Dim dadte_s As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSELECTa, conn)
            comUserSelect = New OleDbCommand(strSELECTa, conn)

            comUserSelect.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
```

*TO DELETE ***

```
 Dim strDelete As String = "delete * from tblvalues "
```

now i don know how to check the condition

Comment: The insert query will be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table_name"
```

If the table is empty, this should return 0.

Alternatively, you could try to select a row from the table and based on the response act upon it.

```
"SELECT * FROM your_table_name LIMIT 0, 1"
```

Comment: hi ovidiu :but in visual basic i was trying to assign that query value to an integer variable , where i was getting stuck , so then i tried with using dataset which solved my prob,                                     and thanks for reply bro

Comment: LIMIT is not supported by Access/Jet/ACE SQL.